# Using UNIQUE indices with NULL fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can check, periodically, for a list of users that are currently online. I want to turn this into something useful like a list of entries per user with login / logout time. There is no other way to determine this information apart from checking who is currently online.
After some thinking I came up with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE onlineActivity (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR (32) NOT NULL,
    login_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    logout_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    time SMALLINT (3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    online BOOL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name, online),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)   ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

I run this query every few minutes to add/update names in the activity list:

```
INSERT INTO onlineActivity (name, login_time, logout_time, online)
    SELECT name, now(), now(), true FROM onlineList ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE logout_time = now()
```

And this query is run for every user that has logged out:
*(the names are determined by comparing two adjacent online lists, the current one and the previous one)*

```
UPDATE onlineActivity SET online = NULL WHERE name = ? AND online = 1
```

---

### The questions:

- I'm worrying that using a NULL field (`online`) in a UNIQUE index is a bad idea, and will hurt performance. I figure that MySQL might have to do a full scan of all the `online`'s (instead of using an index) for each name to find one that is not NULL. Could someone clarify if that is the case here? I couldn't find any information on how MySQL deals with this sort of situation.
- Do other database systems (PostgreSQL, SQLite) behave differently then MySQL in this regard?
- should I instead of the first query, run two queries for each name, to see if a specified user is currently online, and act accordingly on that?
- I thought of this design because I wanted to minimize the amount of queries used, is this a flawed idea in itself?
- This table will be getting around 300~500k new records per day. Is there something else I can do to lessen the performance decrease?

I want to store a full history of user activity, not a single entry.

Comment: Why not make the online BOOL DEFAULT to false? Shouldn't you assume the user is offline if they haven't been recorded as being online?

Comment: Because that will allow only for two entries in the table per user (one online and one offline).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have a unique on name and online since what you are trying to do is create a list of online activity. Putting a unique key as you have specified will mean that you can only have a name in there three times, one for each state (null, true, false).

What you are effectively doing is trying to create a history table in which case to use your current method of populating the table you should put a unique key on (name, logout_time) with a null logout_time indicating a currently logged in user (since you would only want one logout time that is null).

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE onlineActivity (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR (32) NOT NULL,
    login_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    logout_time DATETIME NULL,
    time SMALLINT (3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    online BOOL not null DEFAULT false,
    UNIQUE (name, logout_time),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)   ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Then run this on a schedule to update the table

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO onlineActivity (name, login_time, logout_time, online)
    SELECT name, now(), null, true FROM onlineList
```

And this on user logout

```
UPDATE onlineActivity SET online = false, logout_time = now() WHERE name = ? AND logout_time = null
```

Comment: I *dont* want to have each user represented only once, I want a full history of his activity, and that's what this does. There are dozens of "old" entries for each user, and at most one "current" entry.

Comment: Edited my answer taking that into account.

Comment: There are a few problems with this idea, though. 1) I can't use the first query with the `onlineList`, I need to determine who is online, but wasn't the last time I checked (effectively, who logged in), because this will spam the table with multiple (unwanted) records otherwise. 2) performance wise, nothing changes, there is still a UNIQUE key with a NULL field  3) this doesn't answer any of my questions :p